# How can I use ZF2 forms as a stand-alone module in my PHP application?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, servicemanager

Looking at any kind of basic example on ZF2 forms, I have something like this:

**In Controller** (any basic tutorial example)

```
    $username = new Element\Text('username');
    $username->setLabel('Username')->setAttributes(array(
        'class' => 'username',
        'size' => '30'
    ));

    $form = new Form('my-form');
    $form->add($username);
    return $this->partial("xxx.phtml", array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
```

**In View**

```
/**
 * inside view template
 *
 * @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer $this
 */
echo $this->form($this->form);
```

**Error I get**

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for form' in vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php:557
> Stack trace:
> #0 vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php(161): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('form', true)
> #1 vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(372): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('form', NULL)
> #2 vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(390): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('form')
> #3 module\XXX\view\xxx\xxx.phtml(8): Zend\View\Renderer in vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 557
> ```

I suspect that some fundamental plugin is not set up.  Perhaps even the service that must register the plugin is not set up (ServiceManager)

What can I do to get ZF2 forms working in my otherwisely non-ZF2 app?

My intent is to use ZF2 form component to build forms, and to use them in my php application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not using the full application, the `ViewPluginManager` will not be provided with the names of the *form* view helpers by default; as they live the `Zend\Form\View` namespace.

You can easily register the missing services with a few lines best placed in your 'render factory' if you have one.

```
$viewPluginManager = $render->getHelperPluginManager();

$formConfig = new \Zend\Form\View\HelperConfig();
$formConfig->configureServiceManager($viewPluginManager);

echo $render->form($this->form);
```

Comment: how do you do that that's amazing!!